# Inject UriComponentsBuilder or use static ServletUriComponentsBuilder?

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

Does it make any difference if I inject `UriComponentsBuilder` as parameter into the `@RestController` method, or if I access the uri from static `ServletUriComponentsBuilder` context (fetching it from `RequestContextHolder` underneath)?

```
@RestController
public class MyServlet {
    @GetMapping
    public List<Person> persons(UriComponentsBuilder uri) {
        System.out.println(uri.build().toUriString());
        System.out.println(ServletUriComponentsBuilder.fromCurrentContextPath().toUriString());
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The static factory method that Spring calls behind the scene to provide `UriComponentsBuilder` as method parameter to your class is `fromServletMapping`

```
public static ServletUriComponentsBuilder fromServletMapping(HttpServletRequest request) {
        ServletUriComponentsBuilder builder = fromContextPath(request);
        if (StringUtils.hasText(UrlPathHelper.defaultInstance.getPathWithinServletMapping(request))) {
            builder.path(request.getServletPath());
        }
    return builder;
}
```

And here is the code for `fromContextPath` static factory method that you called: (actually `fromCurrentContextPath` method calls this method with the current request)

```
public static ServletUriComponentsBuilder fromContextPath(HttpServletRequest request) {
    ServletUriComponentsBuilder builder = initFromRequest(request);
    builder.replacePath(request.getContextPath());
    return builder;
}
```

So you can see their result are different when you have a request that contains servlet-mapping: In most Spring applications we have a single servlet and the output of these two are the same.

But what if our request belongs to a servlet with `servlet-path: first/`?

Imagine the following controller:

```
@RestController
public class MyServlet {
    @GetMapping("test")
    public void persons(UriComponentsBuilder uri) {
        System.out.println(
                uri.path("/second/third").build().toUriString());
        System.out.println(
                ServletUriComponentsBuilder.fromCurrentContextPath().path("/second/third").build().toUriString());
    }
}
```

When you send a request to this path Your output will be like this:

http://localhost:8081/first/second/third

http://localhost:8081/second/third

So the first one includes the servlet-path but the second one ignores it.

To have the same result you can use `fromCurrentServletMapping` static fatory method.